# How can I detect a "page's" content type?

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I have begun work on a Drupal website and unfortunately I did not have an opportunity to have them walk me through the website as is.

I'm now trying to replicate content from a development site to a live site, but there is a page which I cannot identify as a particular content type, though I know it is content, because it says on the page "Clone Content."

How can I figure out this page's content type so that I can replicate it? Is this the right question to be asking?

I apologize if this is an ambiguous question, I will clarify any detail needed.

As a side note: Is there any way to clone content *between* Drupal websites? Like exporting and importing? Perhaps a tutorial I should check out?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Upon re-visiting this question that I asked a couple years ago, I wanted to clarify why this issue was unclear. The content type of the node had been deleted, yet the node had remained. Therefore, there was a node with no content type. If you have an issue where the option to clone it does not list the content type, one possibility is that the content type has since been deleted and the node was not deleted with the content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few quick answers to your questions:

1. If you view source on any page, you should see a class name on the body element, something like: node-type-article. This is one way to see the content type. Also, if you edit a page, you'll see that the edit title will look something like this: Edit [content type] [title]
2. Alternatively, navigate to: [domain]/admin/content to see a list of all content, which includes the 'type' column
3. The "clone content" link content comes from a module called "node clone" https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone, designed to allow in-place duplication of content (fields that should not be duplicated are reset to safe values)
4. There is another module that will allow you to export/import nodes between drupal installs: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export It's probably not worth it to get into this unless you have quite a lot of content to move.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful, especially since I'm still getting acclimated to using Drupal.

Comment: NP. there's plenty to get acclimated to :)